# Powershell waitting after click,

Tags: powershell, click

I'm new to powershell.  my problem when i cilck on the validation of a form it takes a varied time.  I would like to know how we delay until the end of the first action to execute the second click, thank you in advance.

Comment: `Start-Sleep` ?

Comment: better with the do while loop

Comment: What form is this? Your own or are you talking about a login page of some kind?

Comment: J'utilise un logiciel de transport, je ferme des centaines de conteneurs dans le système y'on a qui prend 2 minutes pour se fermer et d'autres 2 seconde mon script utilise une boule avec start sleep de 2 minutes exemple pour qu'il ne beug pas ,dans ce cas je le fais manuel c'est plus rapide.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you?

```
Start-Job { Start-Sleep 5;return 60} | wait-job | Receive-Job
```

You could just put whatever you need in the curly braces and then move onto the second task. Just make sure to return the result from inside the job.

Comment: J'utilise un logiciel de transport, je ferme des centaines de conteneurs dans le système y'on a qui prend 2 minutes pour se fermer et d'autres 2 secondes mon script utilise une boule avec start sleep de 2 minutes exemple pour qu'il ne beug pas ,dans ce cas je le fais manuel c'est plus rapide